# Создать бесконечную карусель Owl Carousel, расположение файлов в JS в WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, owl-carousel

Есть страница на WordPress с каруселью на главной странице. Нужно сделать бесконечную карусель, когда прокрутка дойдет до конца, в следующем свайпе будет снова первый элемент. Пробовала менять параметры `loop : true` в *owl.carousel.js*. Изменения в JS файле ни как не отображаются на странице. Есть подозрения, что это неверный JS файл, как можно найти расположение JS-скриптов на страницах WordPress? Пробовала искать через поиск в Total Commander.
Также были подозрения, что дело в том, что JS файл кэшируется, поэтому была попытка добавить параметр версии `date("h:i:s")` в подключении скрипта `wp_enqueue_script('owl.carousel', date("h:i:s"));`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код js в текстовом виде:

```
Owl.Defaults = {
 items: 3,
 loop: true,
 center: false,
 mouseDrag: true,
 touchDrag: true,
 pullDrag: true,
 freeDrag: false,
 margin: 0,
 stagePadding: 0,
 merge: false,
 mergeFit: true,
 autoWidth: false,
 startPosition: 0,
 rtl: false,
 smartSpeed: 250,
 fluidSpeed: false,
 dragEndSpeed: false,
 responsive: {},
 responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
 responsiveBaseElement: window
 responsiveClass: false,
 fallbackEasing: 'swing',
 info: false,
 nestedItemSelector: false,
 itemElement: 'div',
 stageElement: 'div',
 themeClass: 'stm_owl-theme',
 baseClass: 'owl-carousel',
 itemClass: 'owl-item',
 centerClass: 'center',
 activeClass: 'active'
};
```

Comment: Вам нужен файл где инициализируется конкретная Owl карусель (которая отображается на главной), Вы же сейчас вносите правки в исходный файл самой карусели, чего делать категорически не стоит.

Comment: Изменения файла никак не отображаются на странице, так как Вы меняете стандартные настройки карусели, то есть при инициализации они могут быть переопределены. Ищите JS файл в котором инициализируется карусель `$("ЗДЕСЬ КАКОЙ-ТО СЕЛЕКТОР").owlCarousel();`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Спасибо большое :) Поправила

Comment: @Simon Благодарю! Мне помог ваш ответ. Нашла нужный JS файл. Он располагается в `.../wp-content/plugins/masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system/assets/js/vc_modules/courses_carousel/style_1.js`

Comment: Оуууу, ну в плагине менять тоже не стоит, так как после обновления плагина Ваши изменения слетят.

Comment: @Simon Вернула дефолтные значения плагина, обновила, нашла расположение js-файла, внесла свои изменения, вроде все работает. Ура!